# no stack trace on callback in promisifyAll function

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

i'm using the following code to turn this object

```
Extraction = {
  phaseone   : require('./phaseone')
  phasetwo   : require('./phasetwo')
  phasethree : require('./phasethree')
};
```

in promises:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(Extraction);
```

In the first phase, i'm doing all my logic (i can't show here :/) and in the end, when i finish all my operations, i call the callback:

```
var phaseone: function(file, callback) {
    // logic
    callback(result);
};
```

This should call the phasetwo, because i'm calling like this:

```
Extraction.phaseoneAsync(file).then(Extraction.phasetwoAsync);
```

But all this is returning:

Unhandled rejection (<[{"exists":true,"path":"_input/Estapar...>, no stack trace)

What could be this??

Comment: i have the params files and callback.

Comment: i must pass null, files.. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `promisify`, then pass an error as first argument to the callback, that's what `promisify` expects:

```
var phaseone: function(file, callback) {
    // logic
    callback(null, result);
};
```

But if you're going to always use BlueBird, you might as well directly make your API Promise based so that you don't have to promisify it:

```
var phaseone: function(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // logic
        resolve(result);
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer use promisifyAll to maintain my methods clean.

Comment: @celoxxx: Your methods are not inherently asynchronous, are they? What asynchronous API are you using in your methods? Promisify *that*.